# texture baking gray on uvs

Tags: uv, export, texture-baking, baking

Im trying to bake a texture onto the uv and export it so i dont have to start painting the uv from scratch. (or so I can simply use it later for importing)
I will point out that i did separate the object into 3 sections then use nodes to texture and then joined them back before trying to bake uvs. the baked uv with emission node looks fine but if exported it turns gray and doesn't work anymore.
but it does seem that the two parts that were separated are not even being baked and stay the way they are before and after bake.
I did not separate and rejoin after bake, I did it before. so I dont see how thats effecting the texture baking onto uvs. but iv never been good with baking ect. 
so
1. what am i doing wrong?
2.how do i bake the texture to the uvs and export them correctly for later use.
3. is there a way to bake textures to uvs with out shadows. and why isent the ring part being baked after i rejoined it?

[image: parts I separated and rejoined.]

[image: this is the model after bake,using just the uv baked map, and this is the uv exported, its just gray.[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35hk2.png)

Comment: Forgot , the exported uvs can work. but theyer just grayed out uvs if i put them in the image shader there just a slightly gray uv, lines and all. idk if that helps but yeah. and thanks to anyone who trys to help.